# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The inlets [] and outlets [] must correspond to the inlets [Map.in] and outlets []

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am getting the dreadful `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The inlets [] and outlets [] must correspond to the inlets [Map.in] and outlets []` error message and previous SO answers are not helping me.

This is my graph

```
val graph = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(sink){ implicit b =>
  s =>
     import GraphDSL.Implicits._
     val broadcast = b.add(Broadcast[Foo](2))
     val merge = b.add(Merge[Foo](2))
     source ~> func1() ~> broadcast.in
     broadcast.out(0).filter(_.country == "US") ~> usSpecificFilter ~> merge.in(0)
     broadcast.out(1).filter(_.country != "US") ~> internationalFilter ~> merge.in(1)
     merge.out ~> sink
     ClosedShape
})

def func1() : Flow[String, Foo, NotUsed] = {...}
```

From previous threads I could gather that if you have "unused flows" (meaning something which was added to the builder but was not used in the graph) then this error will come.

But as you can see above that I don't have unused flow.

Edit::

```
val graph = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(sink){ implicit b =>
  s =>
     import GraphDSL.Implicits._
     val broadcast = b.add(Broadcast[Foo](2))
     val merge = b.add(Merge[Foo](2))
     val s = b.add(sink)
     source ~> func1() ~> broadcast.in
     broadcast.out(0).filter(_.country == "US") ~> usSpecificFilter ~> merge.in(0)
     broadcast.out(1).filter(_.country != "US") ~> internationalFilter ~> merge.in(1)
     merge.out ~> s.in
     ClosedShape
})
```

Still does not work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your graph, change `merge.out ~> sink` to `merge.out ~> s.in`:

```
val graph = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(sink) { implicit b => s =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val broadcast = b.add(Broadcast[Foo](2))
  val merge = b.add(Merge[Foo](2))
  source ~> func1() ~> broadcast.in
  broadcast.out(0).filter(_.country == "US") ~> usSpecificFilter ~> merge.in(0)
  broadcast.out(1).filter(_.country != "US") ~> internationalFilter ~> merge.in(1)
  merge.out ~> s.in // <--- changed sink to s.in
  ClosedShape
})
```

Comment: That gives a compilation error `value in is not a member of akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink[com.abhi.Foo,scala.concurrent.Future[akka.Done]]`

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch: Are you sure you changed it to `s.in`? The compilation error suggests that you changed it to `sink.in` instead.

Comment: It does not work. I updated my question above. Same problem.

Comment: You don't need `val s = b.add(sink)`.

Comment: it works! thanks! phew sorry for going in circles.! thanks for your patience.